# Jenkins - /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Jenkins installed in ***CentOS*** and installed
Node version ***v14.16.0*** also
npm version **6.14.11**

Failing to execute npm commands like ***npm install***, ***npm cache clean --force*** etc via Jenkins job. Showing /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory in the job console. Same is working fine when we run the same command in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: either npm or node command is not visible to jenkins user. When ever you run a job in Jenkins , Jenkins use jenkins user. make sure jenkins user have access to all the needed tool you need for your build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing following it started working

*sudo ln -sf "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node*